# How to set the ZEGOCLOUD SDK so that the other end cannot hear the sound of the music played by the other end

Tags: zegocloud

I built a video call app using ZEGOCLOUD's SDK.

When `A` (using an oppo phone) and `B` are talking, A wears the headset and uses the music player to play music, then `B` can hear the music played by `A`, I want `B` to listen no music.

How should it be set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The echo cancellation function can be turned on.

```
enableAECWhenHeadsetDetected = true
```

Indicates that echo cancellation is enabled in headphone mode.